OFBIZ: Compiling ofbiz 22.01 fails with "Could not target platform: Java SE 17 using tool chain: JDK 11" . ofbiz 17.12 and 18.12.12 compile succeeds
Questions:
How can I correct the error Could not target platform Java SE 17 using tool chain JDK 11?
What is the correct JDK to compile with for ofbiz 22.01? Ofbiz 17.12 and 18.12.12 use JDK jdk-8u412-b08.
I have used various JDK to compile ofbiz 22.01 without success.
I would like to utilize Apache Ofbiz to build a web store for online
e-commerce. All ofbiz documentation depicts the ofbiz application as localhost on the server and configures reverse proxy server directives to access the ofbiz application on localhost (on the server). My setup is different.
On the LAN, the Ofbiz is behind a reverse proxy.

Reverse proxy is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Ofbiz is on Debian GNU/Linux 12(bookworm) which is a Raspberry 5

This setup works well, except for the ensuing problems.
Over a few months I  learned ofbiz 17.12, 18.12.12, 22.01 utilized gradle release 4.51, 5.0.0, 6.5.1 respectively. I found a compatibility matrix (here) that helped to determine which jdk to use.
Ofbiz Ver  Gradle Ver JDK Adoptopenjdk.net  
 17.12      4.51       jdk-8u412b08          
 18.12.12   5.0.0      jdk-8u412b08
 22.01      6.5.1      jdk-11.0.22+7

Three directories were set-up for each version of ofbiz. The JDK compatible versions were set up in update-alternatives --config java.
Here is a helpful check list

Set Path and Home
vim /etc/profile
export JAVA_HOME = /opt/jdk8u412-b08
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java:${PATH}

Update profile
source /etc/profile


(Per most Ofbiz Instructions)

Download Gradle Wrapper
./gradle/init-gradle-wrapper.sh

Prepare Clean Load Data
./gradlew cleanAll loadAll

Start Ofbiz
./gradlew ofbiz

Visit Ofbiz Thru Browser
https://localhost:8443/accounting


Here is /etc/profile
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi


#export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11.0.22
#export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11.0.23+9
#export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11.0.22+7
#export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-17.0.11+9
#export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-21.0.2+13
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-8u412-b08
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java:${PATH}

Here is update-alternatives --config java
There are 8 choices for the alternative java (providing /bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-arm64/bin/java   1711      auto mode
  1            /opt/jdk-11.0.22+7/bin/java                   10        manual mode
  2            /opt/jdk-11.0.22/bin/java                     70        manual mode
  3            /opt/jdk-11.0.23+9/bin/java                   60        manual mode
  4            /opt/jdk-17.0.11+9/bin/java                   50        manual mode
  5            /opt/jdk-21.0.2+13/bin/java                   20        manual mode
  6            /opt/jdk-22+36/bin/java                       30        manual mode
 *7            /opt/jdk-8u412-b08/bin/java                   40        manual mode
  8            /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-arm64/bin/java   1711      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 

Using the aforementioned guides derived from various online howtos,  I was able to successfully compile ofbiz 17.12 and 18.12.12 which was the goal before moving on to ofbiz 22.01.
The crux of my problem begins when attempting to compile Java with the following:
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11.0.22
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java:${PATH}
update-alternatives --config java <==>  2  /opt/jdk-11.0.22/bin/java 70 manual mode
    

Downloading gradle-wrapper.jar and grale-wrapper.properties - OK
rahab@rahab:/var/www/html/ofbiz-framework-release22.01 $ ****./gradle/init-gradle-wrapper.sh**** 
 === Prepare operation ===
/var/www/html/ofbiz-framework-release22.01/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar not found, we download it
 === Download gradle-wrapper.jar ===
 === Download gradle-wrapper.properties ===
 === Control downloaded files ===
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar: OK
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties: OK
gradlew: OK

Compile fails
rahab@rahab:/var/www/html/ofbiz-framework-release22.01 $ ./gradlew cleanAll loadAll
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Task :buildSrc:extractPluginRequests UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:generatePluginAdapters UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
Task :buildSrc:compileGroovyPlugins UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:pluginUnderTestMetadata UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
Task :buildSrc:compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
Task :buildSrc:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
Task :buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:test NO-SOURCE
Task :buildSrc:validatePlugins UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
Task :buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE
Task :clean
Task :cleanCatalina
Task :cleanData
Task :cleanDownloads
Task :cleanEclipseClasspath UP-TO-DATE
Task :cleanEclipseJdt UP-TO-DATE
Task :cleanEclipseProject UP-TO-DATE
Task :cleanEclipse UP-TO-DATE
Task :cleanFooterFiles
Task :cleanIndexes
Task :cleanLogs
Task :cleanOutput
Task :cleanTempfiles
Task :cleanUploads
Task :cleanXtra
Task :themes:common-theme:cleanNpmInstall UP-TO-DATE
Task :cleanAll
Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.


Could not target platform: 'Java SE 17' using tool chain: 'JDK 11 (11)'.


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 12s
17 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 5 up-to-date
Questions:

How can I correct the error Could not target platform Java SE 17
using tool chain JDK 11?

What is the correct JDK to compile with for ofbiz 22.01? Ofbiz 17.12
and 18.12.12 use JDK jdk-8u412-b08.


I have used various JDK to compile ofbiz 22.01 without success.
Thank you for your time!

Thanks for the edits @Greg Askew.
